# IDS recomended UI?

Tags: ids, snort, monitoring

I been using *Snort* IDS, but I recently switched to *Suricata* IDS since is still community based, etc.

With *Snort* I used to use *Snorby*...

What UI for searching organizing, removing false positives etc do you guys recommend for Suricata IDS that is Open Source non-proprietary?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to go with [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/), there are many templates that help you import and clean the data. Good luck.